# How to dim/turn off the display via ADB?

Tags: android, adb

Good day. I need to ADB turn off the device's Android display. No matter how (change the brightness to 0, turn off power on the screen), it's important for OS to think that the display is turned on. The smartphone is used as a test mini server with a broken sensor, and when you turn off the Power-up screen, the processor speed decreases, resulting in slower performance overall. And some applications just can't work correctly in sleep mode. Smart is controlled through ADB remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Android Shell provide command for Screen on/off via adb shell:

```
screen_info=`adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mInteractive=true`
if [[ $screen_info == *"mInteractive"* ]]
then
echo "Screen is ON"
 #Do something
else
echo "Screen is OFF"
#Do something
fi
```

Happy coding!!